# Product short description with global content in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

wonder if any one can help, php isn't my strongest point. I am trying to create a global short description so I don't have to add it to 2000 products as it will be the same 3 links. I have gone into the theme file directory and i have added the code below to the Short-Description.Php

Now the issue i am having is when i add short description individually within wordpress cms. It shows the 3 links on the single product page and the 3 links i have added from the short-description.php. Thus being two copies of it however when I take out the code from the short description wordpress cms, they both disappear here are my two options i have tried to get working. Hope this makes sense and is probably a simple fix, thank you in advance for your help.

```
     <?php
     /**
      * Single product short description
      *
      * @author  Automattic
      * @package WooCommerce/Templates
      * @version 3.3.0
      */

     if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
     }

     global $post;

     $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

     if ( ! $short_description ) {
        return;
     }

     ?>
     <div class="product-short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
     <p>Our <a href="/always-the-lowest-prices-guaranteed/">Price Guarantee</a><br>
     Interested in <a href="/free-delivery/">Free Delivery?</a><br>
     <a href="/5-year-guarantee/">PremierCare cover</a></p>
     </div>
```

I also created a block to use as a short code - potentially making it easier to change in the future just through a block. This has the same exert of code in to just display the 3 links.

```
<div class="product-short-description">
<?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[block id="short-description-shortcode"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code here:

```
if ( ! $short_description ) {
  return;
}
```

Is saying if no short description exists stop processing the code below which is why nothing is appearing. You can change to:

```
if ( ! $short_description ) {
?>
<div class="product-short-description">
  <p>Our <a href="/always-the-lowest-prices-guaranteed/">Price Guarantee</a><br>Interested in <a href="/free-delivery/">Free Delivery?</a><br>
  <a href="/5-year-guarantee/">PremierCare cover</a></p>
</div>
<?php
} else {
  echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok
}
?>
```

You can probably work out what this code is doing but for clarity. If no short description is set in the CMS use your hard coded content else if you have put a short description in the CMS use that.